# Magento Enterprise Tabs - How to select specific tab in link?

Tags: magento, tabs, prototypejs

I am trying to link to a specific tab in Magento Enterprise.  It seems that all of the answers I've found don't apply well to their method.  I just need a link to the page to also pull up a specific tab.  This is the code they use:

```
Enterprise.Tabs = Class.create();
Object.extend(Enterprise.Tabs.prototype, {
 initialize: function (container) {
    this.container = $(container);
    this.container.addClassName('tab-list');
    this.tabs = this.container.select('dt.tab');
    this.activeTab = this.tabs.first();
    this.tabs.first().addClassName('first');
    this.tabs.last().addClassName('last');
    this.onTabClick = this.handleTabClick.bindAsEventListener(this);
    for (var i = 0, l = this.tabs.length; i < l; i ++) {
        this.tabs[i].observe('click', this.onTabClick);
    }
    this.select();
},
handleTabClick: function (evt) {
    this.activeTab = Event.findElement(evt, 'dt');
    this.select();
},
select: function () {
    for (var i = 0, l = this.tabs.length; i < l; i ++) {
        if (this.tabs[i] == this.activeTab) {
            this.tabs[i].addClassName('active');
            this.tabs[i].style.zIndex = this.tabs.length + 2;
            /*this.tabs[i].next('dd').show();*/
            new Effect.Appear (this.tabs[i].next('dd'), { duration:0.5 });
            this.tabs[i].parentNode.style.height=this.tabs[i].next('dd').getHeight() + 15 + 'px';
        } else {
            this.tabs[i].removeClassName('active');
            this.tabs[i].style.zIndex = this.tabs.length + 1 - i;
            this.tabs[i].next('dd').hide();
        }
    }
}
});
```

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider modifying how the class starts up.

```
initialize: function (container) {
    this.container = $(container);
    this.container.addClassName('tab-list');
    this.tabs = this.container.select('dt.tab');
// change starts here //
    var hashTab = $(window.location.hash.slice(1));
    this.activeTab = ( this.tabs.include(hashTab) ? hashTab : this.tabs.first());
// change ends here //
    this.tabs.first().addClassName('first');
    this.tabs.last().addClassName('last');
    this.onTabClick = this.handleTabClick.bindAsEventListener(this);
    for (var i = 0, l = this.tabs.length; i < l; i ++) {
        this.tabs[i].observe('click', this.onTabClick);
    }
    this.select();
}
```

Here, I have only changed how the initial tab is chosen. It checks for an *URL fragment* which is commonly known as a hash, if that identifies one of the tabs it is preselected. As a bonus the browser will also scroll to that element if possible.

Then you only need to append the tab's ID to the URL. For example you might generate the URL by;

```
$productUrl = Mage::getUrl('catalog/product/view', array(
    'id' => $productId,
    '_fragment' => 'tab_id',
));
```

Comment: Perfect!  Is it also possible to use this method to open a tab from an anchor on the same page without reloading it?

Comment: There is no need to use this method when you're already on the same page. Either click on the tab directly or use Zifius' `selectTab` function.

Comment: Nevermind, Zifius answered this question for me.  Wish I could mark both as an answer!  Thanks a ton.

Comment: The reason I wanted to use it on the same page was because we have a tab that has customer reviews and at the top of the page is a link that says "read reviews."  Customers click the link and nothing happened.  The tabs are "below the fold" if you will, so it's not immediately apparent where the review content is.

Comment: I get that the reviews link changes the fragment. The problem is reacting to such a change, there are at least 3 methods to use depending on the browser. [history.js](https://github.com/balupton/History.js) abstracts these conveniently but it seems like a lot of work for something that's already fixed.

Answer (score 1):

If you've recently migrated from an earlier Magento release, e.g. from Enterprise 1.11 to Enterprise 1.12, make sure the javascript in /template/catalog/product/view.phtml
right after the foreach that generates the tabs gets updated to the 1.12 version:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var collateralTabs = new Enterprise.Tabs('collateral-tabs');
        Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
            collateralTabs.select();
        });
</script>
```

surfimp's VERY helpful suggestions did not produce the desired opening of the closed tab otherwise. Once this updated javascript was added, clicking on a link to read Review or Add Your Review on the product page, jumped to the Reviews tab, even if the tab had been hidden.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Zifius' answer, you can modify the initialize function to just take another argument which will be the active tab.

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
    new Enterprise.Tabs('collateral-tabs', $('tab_review'));
});
```

and then in the scripts.js (or wherever this class may exist for you)

```
initialize: function (container, el) {
    ...
    this.activeTab = el;
    ...
}
```

Use whatever logic in the template you like to set 'el' to the desired value.

The reason I did it this way is because when I used Zifius' method, the desired tab would be the active tab, but the default tab's content was still displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same task yesterday and as I don't know about prototype much I solved it by adding another method:

```js
selectTab: function (element) {
    this.activeTab = element;
    this.select();
},
```

Usage:

```js
var Tabs = new Enterprise.Tabs('collateral-tabs');
Tabs.selectTab($('tabId'));
```

Would like to know if it's a correct approach

Comment: Perhaps you can edit your method to scroll to the ID of the tab's content container?  For my usage, it would allow me to have the best of both worlds.