# Adding Product View Collateral Tabs Magento Enterprise v1.12

Tags: magento

I'm using Magento Enterprise 1.12 and want to add custom tabs (delivery, videos) to the product view page that have their content specified from the product attributes. The script that initialises the tabs is below:

```
//<![CDATA[
    var collateralTabs = new Enterprise.Tabs('collateral-tabs');
        Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
        collateralTabs.select();
    });
//]]>
```

Aside from creating the product attributes I'm not really sure where to start with this, so any help would be much appreciated!

Kind regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tabs in Enterprise are dealt with differently than Community, which can cause problems trying to find a solution.  In catalog.xml you'll find the tabs setup with code like:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.description" as="description" template="catalog/product/view/description.phtml">
<action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
<action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Details</value></action>
</block>
```

So to add another, add another block:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.video" as="video" template="catalog/product/view/video.phtml">
<action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
<action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Video</value></action>
</block>
```

Then create the template file catalog/product/view/video.phtml with whatever content you want the tab to contain.

Whilst that will add a tab just fine, if you want to do it the proper Magento way, the addition should be made using references in the local.xml file of your theme:

```
<catalog_product_view translate="label">
<reference name="product.info">
    <block type="catalog/product_view_description" name="product.video" as="video" template="catalog/product/view/video.phtml" after="product.attributes">
    <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
        <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
        <action method="setTitle" translate="value"><value>Video</value></action>
    </block>
</reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure but i think it is very help full to you see below URL:-

**Magento Enterprise Tabs - How to select specific tab in link?**

[Magento Enterprise Tabs - How to select specific tab in link?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526527/magento-enterprise-tabs-how-to-select-specific-tab-in-link)

**Try it but see the above url first:-**

I would consider modifying how the class starts up.

```
initialize: function (container) {
    this.container = $(container);
    this.container.addClassName('tab-list');
    this.tabs = this.container.select('dt.tab');
// change starts here //
    var hashTab = $(window.location.hash.slice(1));
    this.activeTab = ( this.tabs.include(hashTab) ? hashTab : this.tabs.first());
// change ends here //
    this.tabs.first().addClassName('first');
    this.tabs.last().addClassName('last');
    this.onTabClick = this.handleTabClick.bindAsEventListener(this);
    for (var i = 0, l = this.tabs.length; i < l; i ++) {
        this.tabs[i].observe('click', this.onTabClick);
    }
    this.select();
}
```

Here, I have only changed how the initial tab is chosen. It checks for an URL fragment which is commonly known as a hash, if that identifies one of the tabs it is preselected. As a bonus the browser will also scroll to that element if possible.

Then you only need to append the tab's ID to the URL. For example you might generate the URL by;

```
$productUrl = Mage::getUrl('catalog/product/view', array(
    'id' => $productId,
    '_fragment' => 'tab_id',
));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Abid, but this isn't the question I asked. I want to know how to add additional product tabs not link to a specific one.